# Update model in database using entity framework gives conflict with foreign key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I know this has been asked millions of times and I've had it myself hundreds of times, but for some reason I can't fix this one.

I get the well known error:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ...
```

All my tables in my database are cascaded when an insert or delete is done.

Now on to the error:
I want to update an admins table (administrator accounts) that is linked to a cultures table (for languages).

Everything is filled in correctly. and thus we get to the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Admins admins)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(admins);
        }
        admins.cultures_id = admins.Cultures.id;
        _unitOfWork.AdminsRepository.Update(admins);
        _unitOfWork.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Overview", new { area = "Admin" });
    }
```

I first set the cultures id of my admin object/entity equal to that of the id in the cultures table that is linked:

```
admins.cultures_id = admins.Cultures.id;
```

I then fill update the table:

_unitOfWork.AdminsRepository.Update(admins);

The method update holds this code:

```
    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        ArtWebShopEntity.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

So far so good, but then, when I actually want to save the admin:

```
_unitOfWork.Save();
```

That save method holds this code:

```
        public void Save() {
        try
        {
            _artWebshopEntity.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, validationErrors.Entry.State);

                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            throw;  // Will do something here later on...
        }

    }
```

And at the SaveCHanges method I get the error. I know what it means but I can't seem to fix it. I've tried all the things I know that could cause it.

## Edit

I only want to update the admin values, so I don't want to update the culture values.

This is the query:

```
update [dbo].[Admins]
set    [login] = 'Herve' /* @0 */,
       [password] = null,
       [salt] = null,
       [email] = 'xxxxx.xxx@glevin.be' /* @1 */,
       [permissions] = 'administrator' /* @2 */,
       [attempts] = 4 /* @3 */,
       [locked] = 0 /* @4 */,
       [cultures_id] = 0 /* @5 */
where  ([id] = 1 /* @6 */)
```

So, the cultures_id is the issue. I've now did the following:

```
        var updateAdmin = new Admins
            {
                attempts = admins.attempts,
                cultures_id = admins.cultures_id,
                email = admins.email,
                locked = admins.locked,
                login = admins.login,
                id = admins.id,
                password = admins.password,
                permissions = admins.permissions,
                salt = admins.salt,
            };
```

And that works, but the moment I add the Cultures object to the mix, it crashes and gives me the reference error. So it boils down to, **how the frack do I update a table with a foreign key to another table to also needs to be updated**?

### Edit II

My admin and cultures entity (database first), also image of database in sql management studio:

Admin class:

```
public partial class Admins
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string permissions { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> attempts { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> locked { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cultures_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Cultures Cultures { get; set; }
}
```

Cultures class:

```
public partial class Cultures
{
    public Cultures()
    {
        this.Categories_local = new HashSet<Categories_local>();
        this.Menu_items_local = new HashSet<Menu_items_local>();
        this.Products_local = new HashSet<Products_local>();
        this.Subcategories_local = new HashSet<Subcategories_local>();
        this.Webpages_local = new HashSet<Webpages_local>();
        this.Admins = new HashSet<Admins>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Categories_local> Categories_local { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu_items_local> Menu_items_local { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Products_local> Products_local { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subcategories_local> Subcategories_local { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Webpages_local> Webpages_local { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Admins> Admins { get; set; }
}
```

[image: database design]

Comment: Launch SqlProfiler to see what query is being executed. This should indicate what is missing.

Comment: And where can I find this?

Comment: You will find the SQL profiler in the SQL the Management Studio.

Comment: also in the express version? Because I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Not sure that the SQL profiler exists in the SQL Express Management Studio.

Comment: No profiler makes things a whole lot harder. Install [this tool](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof).

Comment: Now there is a convenient tool, too bad it's pretty expensive to buy (for me). But it'll help me for the next 33 days :D.

Comment: so, as I thought, and now supported by Entity framework profiler, it's because the update statement is also trying to update the culture id.

Now, anyone got an idea on how I can pass everything except the FK cultures_id?

Comment: Could you show us your model(edmx) or configuration, if you use ef-code-first. I need to look at your navigation property culture of admin entity.

Comment: Added it to the OP under Edit II.

Comment: Can you show your model declarations? I wonder if the problem is the reference from the Admins model to the Culture model.

Comment: I've added it, didn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it to work!

The problem was that in the edit page the final field was the field that showed the name of the culture that corresponded with the id of the admin.

In other words I did the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cultures.name)
```

But this wasn't the correct way.

In order to show the name of the culture but in the code pass the culture id, I used a @Html.DropDownListFor()-element.

The problem with this however was that my original model, **Admins**, didn't have a IEnumerable object that I could pass to the dropdownlist element in my view. I had to create a new model which I named **CreateAdminModel**, The new model looks like this:

```
public class CreateAdminModel
{
    public CreateAdminModel() { }

    public CreateAdminModel(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cultures) { Cultures = cultures; }

    public CreateAdminModel(Admins admin) { Admin = admin; }

    public CreateAdminModel(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cultures, Admins admin)
    {
        Cultures = cultures;
        Admin = admin;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cultures { get;  set; }
    public Admins Admin { get; internal set; }
}
```

It has an Admin object created by the entity framework (database first).

With that new model I created the following method:

```
    private CreateAdminModel CreateAdminWithcultureDetails(Admins admin = null)
    {
        var cultureItems = (_unitOfWork.CulturesRepository.Get()).ToArray();
        var cultureList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cultureItems.Count(); i++) cultureList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = cultureItems[i].name, Value = cultureItems[i].id.ToString() });

        return admin != null ? new CreateAdminModel(cultureList, admin) : new CreateAdminModel(cultureList);
    }
```

This fills the dropdown list with the cultures and depending on whether or not an admin object was passed also adds an admin object.

Now I can use this model in the view and correctly fill both the dropdown list and the admin if necessary.

I'm going to do the same for the other things that have to use CRUD.